# Help with Pager

Tags: 7, paging

I am using the Drupal 7 and i want to use the Pager into my query

This is my query and the way i can use

```
$qury = db_select("SELECT `entity_id` , `field_keywords_value` , COUNT( DISTINCT ( `entity_id` )) total 
FROM `field_data_field_keywords`
WHERE `bundle` = 'song' 
GROUP BY `field_keywords_value`");

$query = $qury->extend('PagerDefault'); 
        $result = $query
  ->extend('PagerDefault')
  ->limit(2)
  ->execute();
```

but it give me the error, PDOException: erro

And if i can use it in the following way:

```
$qury = db_query("SELECT `entity_id` , `field_keywords_value` , COUNT( DISTINCT ( `entity_id` )) total FROM `field_data_field_keywords` WHERE `bundle` = 'song'
                GROUP BY `field_keywords_value`");
$query = $qury->extend('PagerDefault'); 
$result = $query
  ->extend('PagerDefault')
  ->limit(2)
  ->execute();
echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
die('tert');
```

Then my page not working and give me the blank page.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You have a typo in your code: The first line uses `$qury` as variable, while the others use `$query`. You are also extending twice `$query` with the same class, when doing it once is enough.

Comment: May you report the exact error you are given?

Answer (score 4):

First check which Drupal version you are using

if using Drupal 7 the use see below given example

```
    <?php
$result = db_select('table_name', 'table_alias')
    ->fields('table_alias',array('column_name1', 'column_name2', 'column_name1', .....))//SELECT the fields from user
    ->condition('type', 'article')
    ->extend('PagerDefault')
    ->limit(10)  // Set the limit per records
    ->orderBy('created_date', 'DESC')//ORDER BY created or 
    ->execute()
    ->fetchAssoc();
?>
```

See more example at

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_select/7

Answer (score 1):

Check [examples module](http://drupal.org/project/examples) how pager is given in this.

You are using select in select query. So its giving exception error.

For running SQL queries as it is, use db_query().
ex:- db_query("select emmpno from emp")
For running db_select() we need to follow Drupal standards.
ex:- $query=db_select('emp','e');
$result=$query->fields()->execute();

No select in a select.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But i am  new in Drupal and i dont know how i can use this query according to D7 rule. Can you please help me to resolve this issue. thank in advance

Comment: Try this code                                                             $qeury = db_query("SELECT `entity_id` , `field_keywords_value` , COUNT( DISTINCT ( `entity_id` )) total FROM 'field_data_field_keywords' WHERE 'bundle` = ':dub'",array(':bun'='song') GROUP BY `n.field_keywords_value`");
$qeury->extend('PagerDefault'); 
$result = $query
    ->limit(2)
  ->execute();
echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
die('tert');
foreach($result as $row)
{
//Your code for each row
}

Comment: Thanks for your reply. but yesterday i have resolved the porblem by my self like: $query = db_select('field_data_field_keywords')->extend('PagerDefault');
  $query->fields('field_data_field_keywords', array('field_keywords_value', 'entity_id'));
  $query->condition('bundle', 'song');
  $query->condition('field_keywords_value', arg(2));
  $query->distinct(entity_id);
   $result = $query
    ->limit(1)
    ->execute()
    ->fetchAll();   hope this is help ful for someone who is new in D7 thanks

Comment: May you expand your answer? Answers that are merely a link are not considered answers, on Drupal Answers.

Answer (score 1):

An example Drupal 7 query with joins, conditions, limit and pagination:

```
$query = db_select('table_name1', 't1');
$query->join('table_name2', 't2', 't.id = t2.tid');
$query
->fields('t1', array('column1', 'column2', 'column3'))
->fields('t2', array('column1'))
->condition(db_or()->condition('t1.column2', '%' . db_like($match) . '%', 'LIKE')
                              ->condition('t2.column1', 'string', '=')
);

if($user->uid > 0) { $query->condition('t2.column2', '1', '='); } // only for logged in user

$query->groupBy('t1.id');
$search_results = $query->extend('PagerDefault')->limit(5)->execute(); // set pagination
```

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the problem bye my self

```
 $query = db_select('field_data_field_keywords')->extend('PagerDefault'); 
 $query->fields('field_data_field_keywords', array('field_keywords_value', 'entity_id'));    
 $query->condition('bundle', 'song');  $query->condition('field_keywords_value', arg(2)); 
 $query->distinct('entity_id');
 $result = $query ->limit(1)->execute()->fetchAll();
```

hope this is helpful for someone who is new in D7.

Answer (score 0):

// $list is the list of items you are paging through

$list = array ('Cat','Dog','Mouse','Horse','Pony','Winged mongoose');
$per_page = 2;

// Initialise the pager

$current_page = pager_default_initialize(count($list), $per_page);

// Split your list into page sized chunks

$chunks = array_chunk($list,$per_page, TRUE);

// Show the pager

print theme('pager', array('quantity',count($list)));

// Show the appropriate items from the list

print theme('item_list', array(
   'items' => $chunks[$current_page],
));